# Symfony logged in lost after login (with ajax)

Tags: php, symfony

I am stuck with a problem and I am looking hours for a solution. I can login in my website, a session attribute is made but after a page refresh I am not authenticated (and token is still in the session).

Symfony version: 2.3

My security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        XXX\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 3
        XXX\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 3

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        users:
            entity: { class: XXXCustomerBundle:Customer }
        admin:
            entity: { class: XXXUserBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        XXX:
            pattern: ^/[^admin]
            context: "XXX"
            anonymous: true
            provider: users
            form_login:
                check_path: ps_customer_logincheck
                login_path: ps_customer_login
                success_handler: ps_customer.authentication_handler
                failure_handler: ps_customer.authentication_handler
                username_parameter: "ps_customer_login[email]"
                password_parameter: "ps_customer_login[password]"

        XXX_admin_nologin:
            pattern: ^/admin/login$
            security: false

        XXX_admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            context: "XXX_admin"
            anonymous: false
            provider: admin
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: ps_category_admin_overview
                check_path: ps_user_logincheck
                login_path: ps_user_login
                username_parameter: "ps_user_login[username]"
                password_parameter: "ps_user_login[password]"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The problem relies in the "XXX" firewall, the admin works fine.

My customer entity returns an array with one role ROLE_USER so that couldn't be problem.

After a login the session data looks like:
[image]

My sessions are stored on disk. I hope someone can point me to the right direction since I am bumping my head against the wall right now.

Comment: Is the authentication token set in the debug toolbar when you revisit the page you were trying to access before you get redirected to login_path?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I finally fixed it myself, spend 10 hours on such a simple problem. Actually debugging is easy when you anonymous true and your debug bag says 'Your are not authenticated' should indicate that there is something wrong because you should ALWAYS be authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh gosh, the answer was very simple, the regular expression wasn't valid. Although I am quite sure it worked before.

Anyway changing my firewall patterns did the trick:

```
XXX:
    pattern: ^/(?!admin)

XXX_admin:
    pattern: ^/admin
```

Works perfect right now :)